# ArcGIS REST API to create a site using a template

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, template

We are exploring the ArcGIS REST API to set up a site using any available template(initiative). e.g. need to create a site using template "Active Transportation Outreach". Is there any REST API available to automate this process and initiate from any external application?
[image]